# how to double pipe candump

Tags: grep, pipe, can-bus, canutils

when using candump to read can bus :

```
$ candump can0
```

if I grep it once :

```
$ candump can0 | grep <whatever>
```

It works perfectly :

```
  $ candump can0 | grep 1A8           
  can0  1A8   [8]  3C 53 C5 FF 0D C3 3A 01
  can0  1A8   [8]  3C 53 C5 FF 0D C3 3A 01
```

If I try to grep it twice :

```
candump can0 | grep 1A8 | grep 1A8
```

it returns nothing ...

Ps : it might be solved by using this ( `candump can0,<whatever>,7ff | grep <whatever>` but it only works in that precise case )

Edit: for clarity, if I grep twice the same things it's still not working

Comment: What is the expected output? There might be zero lines that match both greps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue does not come from `candump` but from `grep` that buffer the output.

You can find a good explanation of this behavior [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/562352).